# How to show only month and year of date in DataColumn of Datatable?

Tags: c#, mysql, c#-2.0

I am populating one DataGridView in C# windows application. I have one DataTable in which I am displaying dates which I retrieve from database. My problem is, dates that I am getting from database includes time information also. For example: Jan 2003 12:00:00 AM.

I want to show only the year and month (Jan 2003) part of that date in cells of datatable. I tried to change the culture information of current thread, but it didnt worked. Is there any other way to achieve this?

I am using MySQLas my database and there I have set datatype of this column as DATE, but I am still getting this time information. Can anyone explain this behavior of MySQL as well?

Comment: How do you populate the DataGridView?

Comment: by setting datasource property of datagridview to datatable

Comment: Ok, maybe I'm misunderstanding this. But if you are binding the DataGridView's datasource to the DataTable (from the DB), and you're displaying this information - can't you use DataFormatString on the DataGridView's BoundColumn/TemplateColumn?  This means you abstract the date up from MySql to the DT, then to DGV which handles the cosmetics...

Comment: ^^ just read: "windows application", please ignore my last comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format.aspx) property on your column to [the Month/Year format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#YearMonth):

```
// Set the Format property on the "Last Prepared" column to cause
// the DateTime to be formatted as "Month, Year".
dataGridView1.Columns["Last Prepared"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "y";
```

Comment: Great answer. I know this is outdated, but I wanted to add [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) reference that has all the date/time formats.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to do this at the SQL level, you can do this in your select;

```
select convert(varchar(max),getdate(),107) as thedate
```

I'd always recommend not abstracting the data and letting the datagridview doing the cosmetics however.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.
I solved my problem by changing my query. I used date_format() function of MySql which gave me exact format .
Here is the link which gives more information about this function.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format